# Set on symbol with OwnValues skips UpValues

Tags: assignment

Can anyone provide insight on what's going on here?

First I define a new `Set` behavior for a symbol:

```
mySym /: Set[mySym[f_], v_] := v

mySym[1] = 2

(* Out *) 2

mySym[1]

(* Out *) mySym[1]
```

Works great

But if we provide an alias for this symbol the [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) never get called:

```
ms = mySym;

ms[1] = 2

(* Out *) 2

mySym[1]

(* Out *) 2
```

Even more, if we pre-[`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) that `ms` we still have an issue:

```
Evaluate[ms][1] = 3

(* Out *) 3

mySym[1]

(* Out *) 3
```

Although `With` does the appropriate thing:

```
With[{m = ms},
 m[1] = 4
 ]

(* Out *) 4

mySym[1]

(* Out *) 3
```

What's the cause of that? It's single-handedly nixed an OO implementation I was working on.

Comment: Just a side note, `Evaluate` is too deep in `Set` to work, isn''t it?

Comment: @Kuba oh true. Nice of Mathematica to support that syntax anyway...

Comment: @Kuba one thing worth noting is that this syntax is supported: `Evaluate@Symbol["sym"][1] = 1` which is what made me think the other should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But if we provide an alias for this symbol the UpValues never get called:

`Set` is `HoldFirst`. That means that its first argument does not get evaluated before it is passed to `Set`.  `ms[1] = 2` never gets transformed to `mySym[1] = 2`.

It is true that internally `Set` will examine its first argument and will evaluate it *sometimes*. That is why in this case the definition `mySym[1] = 2` gets created.  But that happens internally within `Set`. The expression `mySym[1] = 2`, which could trigger the UpValues rule, never materializes.

> Even more, if we pre-Evaluate that ms we still have an issue:

`Evaluate` works only at level 1 within a held expression.

```
Hold[Evaluate[1 + 1]]
(* Hold[2] *)

Hold[{Evaluate[1 + 1]}]
(* Hold[{Evaluate[1 + 1]}] *)
```

Whenever the evaluator encounters a symbol with a `Hold*` attribute, it will check for any `Evaluate` within the first level only, and act accordingly.

Comment: Yeah the `Evaluate` was just confusion on my part. The fact that `ms` never gets transformed to `mySym` but `mySym` *still* gets the `OwnValue` is slightly confusing, honestly. That this fails is well known: `a = 1; a[2] = 3`. But that the `OwnValues` replacement never happens is odd. Certainly a "gotcha" that's a bit hard to debug around.

Comment: If the LHS of Set evaluated freely then after `a=1`, `a=2` could not work because it would transform to `1=2`.

Comment: Good point. I'd honestly almost prefer no evaluation than occasional *internal* evaluation though. But I'm sure there's a design reason for it. Also do you know why the `Evaluate` syntax is supported? Is it for things like this: `Evaluate@Symbol["s"] = 1`?

Comment: @b3m2a1 *"Also do you know why the Evaluate syntax is supported?"* - This is not  like some special "syntax" is supported. `Set` is `HoldFirst`, and as such, obeys the standard evaluation semantics of `HoldFirst` attribute in Mathematica - in particular that `Evaluate` can override it. There is no special rule added for `Set` to make `Evaluate` work - it follows from the general evaluation semantics of the language.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin the oddity for me is/was that things like `Evaluate[Symbol["sym"]][1] = 1` worked, but then I found out that `Symbol["sym"][1] = 5` works, although `Symbol["sym"] = 5` does not, so maybe it's just ignoring the `Evaluate` there. The skipping of the `UpValues` just threw me for a loop.

Comment: @b3m2a1 What happens when you write `Set[f[args], rhs]` is that `f` and `args` separately are evaluated by `Set`, but not `f[args]`. In your example, for `Symbol["sym"][1] = 5`, the `f` is `Symbol["sym"]`, which is why it evaluates. In the second case, `f` is `Symbol`, which is why `Symbol["sym"]` does not evaluate. There are reasons for why this is so - otherwise in many cases `Set` will not behave as one would expect. But this was clearly a design decision. I discussed this in my answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7408310/565518) is a bit more detail.