# List assigment ({...}={...}) and UpValues

Tags: language-design, upvalues

Let's say I want to track any assignment attempt for a variable `a`:

```
a /: Set[a, x_] := Print@{a, x}
```

This works as intended:

```
a = 5
(* {a,5} *)

a
(* a *)
```

However, this doesn't catch the `{...}={...}` syntax:

```
({a, b} = {1, 2})
(* {1, 2} *)

a
(* 1 *)
```

And the following obviously does not work:

```
a /: Set[{___, a, ___}, x_] := Print@{a, x}
```

> ```
> TagSetDelayed::tagpos: Tag a in {___, a, ___} = x_ is too deep for an assigned rule to be found.
> ```

```
(* $Failed *)
```

This leads to the following two questions:

- Is there any way to "nice" way to achieve such functionality? (By "nice" I mean something similar to assigning the definition to the upvalues of `a`, as opposed to e.g. `Unprotect`ing `List`/`Set` and attaching the definition there)
- Why does `Set` not simply "thread" over the lists to give upvalue definitions a chance to catch the assignment? As it stands, this potentially breaks many "smart" symbols (e.g. file backed symbols) if the user ever decides to use the list assignment syntax. Is there anything what would not work if this would be the case?

Comment: Would you say this a duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155480/38205)? As Szabolcs points out there for a similar problem, that threaded `Set` is probably internal. There are a few ways you could work around this, depending on what you need done, but none that use exactly this syntax, I think.

Comment: That question is surely related, but I think this one is different enough. Here I ask for a workaround of this particular problem and a reason why this behavior was chosen, while the other one is more concentrated on why this happens.

Comment: If you just need to know that an assignment was attempted, and not the value of the assignment, you could just do `Protect[a]`.